# Customize CKeditor/IMCE file upload function

Tags: 6, wysiwyg, files

D6 with CKeditor Module, CKeditor 3.6.4, and IMCE

This setup is working fine, but I dont want to use the 'Browse Server' Dialog. The ideal solution is to use the 'Insert File' Button (found on the Browse Server Dialog) instead.

So that the user is on a ckeditor form, clicks the image button, and on that dialog there is a button to upload a file instead of the 'Browse Server' button..everything else is the same. I'm looking on doing something similar on the link button.